# How to develop a neural network to predict joint angles form joint positions and orientation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am all new to neural network. I have a dataset of 3d joint positions (6400*23*3) and orientations in quaternions  (6400*23*4) and I want to predict the joint angles for all 22 joints and 3 motion planes (6400*22*3). I have tried to make a model however it will not run as the input data don't match the output shape, and I can't figure out how to change it.

my code

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
Jaload = scipy.io.loadmat('JointAnglesXsens11MovementsIforlængelse.mat') 
Orload = scipy.io.loadmat('OrientationXsens11MovementsIforlængelse.mat')
Or = np.array((Orload['OR'][:,:]), dtype='float')
Ja = np.array((Jaload['JA'][:,:]), dtype='float')
Jalabel = np.array(Ja)
a = 0.6108652382 
Jalabel[Jalabel<a] = 0
Jalabel[Jalabel>a] = 1
Ja3d = np.array(Jalabel.reshape(6814,22,3)) # der er 22 ledvinkler 
Or3d = np.array(Or.reshape(6814,23,4)) # der er 23 segmenter
X_train = np.array(Or3d)
Y_train = np.array(Ja3d)
model = Sequential([
  Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(23,4)),
  Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  Dense(3, activation='softmax'),])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam') # works 
model.fit(
  X_train,
  to_categorical(Y_train),
  epochs=3,)
```

Running the model.fit returns with:
ValueError: A target array with shape (6814, 22, 3, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions that might get you further down the road:
(1) You might want to insert a "Flatten()" layer just before the final Dense.  This will basically collapse the output from the previous layers into a single dimension.
(2) You might want to make the final Dense layer have 22*3=66 units as opposed to three.  Each output unit will represent a particular joint angle.
(3) You might want to likewise collapse the Y_train to be (num_samples, 22*3) using the numpy reshape.
(4) You might want to make the final Dense layer have "linear" activation instead of "softmax" - softmax will force the outputs to sum to 1 as a probability.
(5) Don't convert the y_train to categorical.  It is already in the correct format I believe (after you reshape it to match the revised output of the model).
(6) The metric to use is probably not "categorical_crossentropy" but perhaps "mse" (mean squared error).

Hopefully, some of the above will help move you in the right direction.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Masilila what version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: @FrederikPetri I'm using TensorFlow 2.0